# Regex Pattern to allow alphabets ignoring case sensitivity

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation, regex-group, regex-greedy

Have a regex pattern for password during registration. Requirement being "Use 8 or more characters with a mix of letters, numbers and symbols"

Have the regex which works for above requirement, Presently regex pattern checks for atleast on upper case letter which is not required. Only letter should be present irrespective of case. What should be modified in my below show regex pattern.

```
<f:validateRegex pattern="((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{8,15})"/>
```

I have searched various blogs to get the specific solution but exact need was not fulfilled. Only thing concluded was to use /i to ignore case. Since i am not comfortable with regex building and have not worked in past so wanted the modification which should be done to present regex.

Comment: Use `[a-zA-Z]` to match letters case insensitively.

Answer (score 0):

If the above pattern is case sensitive (looks like it must include lowercase `a` to `z`), try adding `A-Z` to the `a-z` pattern.

That is:

```
<f:validateRegex pattern="((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{8,15})"/>
```

Comment: Above modification does not work still it checks for atleast one Uppercase letter. abc@123456 does not work and aBc@123456 works.  Want abc@123456 also to work

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the language or how it is being used, but here an example in JavaScript with [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qwjftm9e/)

Comment: This is what is being used in JS  :                                                                         
 var regex = /(?=^.{8,15}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&amp;*()_+}{&quot;:;'?/&gt;.&lt;,])(?!.*\s).*$/;

Comment: That one is working in the updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g98us4wj/). Can you check the fiddle to see if the examples that I've put together representative of what you are trying to do? Or can you create your own fiddle that shows it failing?